# hibernate Configuration class with multiple DataSource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mysql-workbench

Our application need to deal with multiple databases. We tried to configure multiple data sources through Hibernate configuration and added two configurations one for database 1 and second for database 2. This configuration fails with following Exception

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: sessionFactory1,sessionFactory2
Nov 29, 2019 5:08:11 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: sessionFactory1,sessionFactory2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
```

This is my Configuration class :

```
package com.pack1.config;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

import com.pack1.routing.MyRoutingDataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.pack1")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement

// Load to Environment
@PropertySources({@PropertySource("classpath:ds/datasource-cfg.properties")})

public class ApplicationContextConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{


    // The Environment class serves as the property holder
    // and stores all the properties loaded by the @PropertySource
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    // Returns Routing DataSource (MyRoutingDataSource)
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource(DataSource dataSource1, DataSource dataSource2) {

        System.out.println("## Create DataSource from dataSource1 & dataSource2");

        MyRoutingDataSource dataSource = new MyRoutingDataSource();

        Map<Object, Object> dsMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        dsMap.put("PUBLISHER_DS", dataSource1);
        dsMap.put("ADVERTISER_DS", dataSource2);

        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(dsMap);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource1")
    public DataSource getDataSource1() throws SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // See: datasouce-cfg.properties
        dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("ds.database-driver1"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("ds.url1"));
        dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("ds.username1"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("ds.password1"));

        System.out.println("## getDataSource1: " + dataSource);

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties1() 
    {
        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("ds.hibernate.dialect1", env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.dialect1"));
        props.setProperty("ds.hibernate.show_sql1", env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.show_sql1"));

        return props;
    }

 // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int

    private int getIntProperty1(String propName) {

        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);

        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);

        return intPropVal;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory1() throws SQLException, PropertyVetoException{

        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        // set the properties
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource1());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.packagesToScan1"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties1());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager1(SessionFactory sessionFactory1) {

        // setup transaction manager based on session factory 
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();

        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory1);

        return txManager;
    }


    @Bean(name = "dataSource2")
    public DataSource getDataSource2() throws SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // See: datasouce-cfg.properties
        dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("ds.database-driver2"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("ds.url2"));
        dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("ds.username2"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("ds.password2"));

        System.out.println("## getDataSource2: " + dataSource);

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties2() 
    {
        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("ds.hibernate.dialect2", env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.dialect2"));
        props.setProperty("ds.hibernate.show_sql2", env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.show_sql2"));

        return props;
    }

 // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int

    private int getIntProperty2(String propName) {

        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);

        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);

        return intPropVal;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory2() throws SQLException, PropertyVetoException{

        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory1 = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        // set the properties
        sessionFactory1.setDataSource(getDataSource2());
        sessionFactory1.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("ds.hibernate.packagesToScan2"));
        sessionFactory1.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties2());

        return sessionFactory1;
    }


    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManage2(SessionFactory sessionFactory1) {

        // setup transaction manager based on session factory 
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();

        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory1);

        return txManager;
    }

}
```

Dao class :

```
package com.pack1.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class DataDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport {


     @Autowired
     @Qualifier(value="t1")
     private SessionFactory firstDBSessionFactory;


       public List<Publisher> queryPublishers() {

            // get the current hibernate session
            Session currentSession = firstDBSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

            // create a query 
            Query<Publisher> theQuery = 
                    currentSession.createQuery("from Publisher", Publisher.class);

            // execute query and get result list
            List<Publisher> customers = theQuery.getResultList();

            // return the results
            return customers;

            return customers;
          }


        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(value="t2")
        private SessionFactory secondDBSessionFactory;


        @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=true, value="t2")
        public List<Advertiser> queryAdvertisers() {

            // get the current hibernate session
            Session currentSession = secondDBSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

            // create a query 
            Query<Advertiser> theQuery = 
                    currentSession.createQuery("from Advertiser", Advertiser.class);

            // execute query and get result list
            List<Advertiser> customers = theQuery.getResultList();

            // return the results
            return customers;

        }

        }

        public List<String> queryDashboard() {

            return null;
        }
}
```

Properties file :

```
# DataSource (PUBLISHER System).

ds.database-driver1=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
ds.url1=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/pan_db
ds.username1=hbstudent
ds.password1=hbstudent


# DataSource (ADVERTISER System).

ds.database-driver2=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
ds.url2=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/voter_db
ds.username2=hbstudent
ds.password2=hbstudent


#
# Hibernate properties1
#
ds.hibernate.dialect1=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
ds.hibernate.show_sql1=true
ds.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto1=update


#
# Hibernate properties2
#
ds.hibernate.dialect2=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
ds.hibernate.show_sql2=true
ds.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto2=update
```

SpringWebAppInitializer class :

```
package com.pack1.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {


            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            ctx.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);
            ctx.setServletContext(servletContext); // ②

            Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",new DispatcherServlet(ctx)); // ③
            servlet.addMapping("/*");
            servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

            servletContext.addFilter("name", CharacterEncodingFilter.class)
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

        }



    /*@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
    {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");       
        // 
        dispatcher.setInitParameter("contextClass", appContext.getClass().getName());

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));

        // UTF8 Charactor Filter.
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);

        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }*/

    }
```

WebMvcConfigurerAdapter Class :

```
package com.pack1.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.pack1.intercepter.DataSourceIntercepter;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
    {

        // Default..
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    //
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(new DataSourceIntercepter())//
                .addPathPatterns("/publisher/*", "/advertiser/*");
    }
}
```

following exception is :

```
INFO: Server startup in [8,376] milliseconds
Dec 05, 2019 12:05:18 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /multiple_DB1/
Dec 05, 2019 12:05:22 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /multiple_DB1/
Dec 05, 2019 12:05:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /multiple_DB1/
```

I am new to using multiple Datasource in Spring MVC. Please help me Coding in Hibernate Configuration class .

Comment: Can you add dataDAO class as well? Issue seems to be different here.

Comment: Hello brother i Have added dao class also ,I  am new  for this application please advise me

Comment: @RakeshYadav Are you still looking ?

Comment: @Yogendra123 Hello Bro, Under Process can we create SessionFactory With out JdbcTemplate

Comment: Yes, you can, I have updated the repo, please check the controller class how to use sessionFactory

Comment: in your controller class you used jdbctemplate ,i want hibernate session Factory in dao class  LIKE THIS  ---->
     public List<Publisher> queryPublishers() {
        
      // get the current hibernate session
      Session currentSession = ((SessionFactory) jdbcTemplate1).getCurrentSession();
      
      // create a query 
      Query<Publisher> theQuery = 
        currentSession.createQuery("from Publisher", Publisher.class);
      
     
      List<Publisher> customers = theQuery.getResultList();
      
     
      return customers;
      
     }

Comment: I have updated the answer and repo as well, please check, there is one example using jdbcTemplate and one sessionFactory

Comment: Its Executing but ,small error  Dec 04, 2019 6:08:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /multiple_DB1/

Comment: That is completely different error, please start a new thread for that. If my solution worked for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: handler mapping is not founding ,but i have accepted your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below Configuration file

```
package com.yogendra.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean("datasource1")
public DataSource dataSource1() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("app1.db.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("app1.db.URL"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("app1.db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("app1.db.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean("datasource2")
public DataSource dataSource2() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("app2.db.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("app2.db.URL"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("app2.db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("app2.db.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean("jdbc1")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource1());
}

@Bean("jdbc2")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource2());
}

@Bean("session1")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory1() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource1());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.yogendra" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean("session2")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory2() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource2());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.yogendra" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean("tx1")
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager1() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory1().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean("tx2")
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager2() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory2().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
            setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        }
    };
 }

 }
```

And here is properties files

```
 app1.db.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
 app1.db.URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test_db
 app1.db.username=postgres
 app1.db.password=postgres


 app2.db.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
 app2.db.URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test_db2
 app2.db.username=postgres
 app2.db.password=postgres
```

You can find working code [here](https://github.com/yogi0209/spring-mvc-multi-datasource)

See how you can use the sessionFactory

```
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("session2")
   SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @GetMapping(value = "/test2")
   @Transactional("tx2")
   public void test2() {
    List<String> cities = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select city from address")
            .list();
    System.out.println("------------ citties ------------ " + cities);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need multiple configuration files for each database and one of them needs to be declared as `Primary`. I am providing you some examples to have an idea what you need.

`PrimaryDB` is declared the primary database for the project. Primary means that the JPA by default will be executed on the primary database.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = {"com.example.repositories.primary"})
public class PrimaryDBConfig {

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "primaryDatasource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "primary.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("primaryDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.example.entities.primary")
        .persistenceUnit("primary").build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "primaryTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
      @Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);

  }
}
```

A second configuration file about our second database `FooDB`

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "fooEntityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = {"com.example.repositories.foo"})
public class FooDBConfig {

  @Bean(name = "fooDatasource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "fooEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("fooDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.example.entities.crf")
        .persistenceUnit("foo").build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "fooTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
      @Qualifier("fooEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

In addition, you will need to add the following on `application.properties`, because Spring will listen to the default data source configuration.

```
primary.datasource.url= URL
primary.datasource.username=username
primary.datasource.password=password


foo.datasource.url=URL
foo.datasource.username=username
foo.datasource.password=password
```

Comment: Hello Brother, I am new to Spring MVC Can you Convert JPA to  Hibernate Properties and show me Imports also.

Comment: Please advice me